# php curl_setop url error

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a 
$result = curl_exec($ch)
the $ value is like that

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 12:45:05 GMT
Set-Cookie: OAMAuthnHintCookie=0@1524055505; httponly; secure; path=/; domain=.test.com
Set-Cookie: OAMRequestContext_test.test.com:443_527635=Rv52rjM82f3htVYzT+Lp0g==;max-age=300; httponly; secure; path=/
Location: https://id.test.com/obrareq.cgi?encquery%3DE6zb4nAIzYfopY8L5SbbJJPLfvrkN7Y1RkKgv4%2FSzBKmT1cY%2BhRn0A3AhCDxGFIB10DLwLMp%2BcR40CHFKhdrh2aZcEck%2Bd2pzikJ3WzWCAo5LiVW8O3CGPVoeFXUBY2orJxN9zSZXNXkAzg%2F%2F2twT%2FS1ZIUlox8fyQrKf6mITSrqbgKhn5dcC5CR79rJDCO75VEIU472JptWmPlBlEkyFT1XRO%2BUzXQHUwui92%2FGCh34PbbDrPajiyU71ycb03ffcCt0Sl1tKVNw2S%2BsUe81VH1jgV8yLWXslvl2SzsqpQUcZVZdi80HEM2ppQTsvECX%2BiyWnZ49nVBxp3YqU4nlhkAIaNaEbTEpPVF%2FvCJSuHo%3D%20agentid%3DWgtest%20ver%3D1%20crmethod%3D2
Content-Length: 676
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 12:45:05 GMT
```

I extract the location: url with:

```
preg_match('/(Location: https:\/\/id\.test\.com\/obrareq\.cgi\?encquery)(.*)/', $res, $location);
```

and put the result in $found:

```
$found=$location[2];
```

then I want to use this url in a new curl_setop

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://id.test.com/obrareq.cgi?encquery'.$found);
......
```

but it doesn't give me any result.

If I do the same curl_setop with a manual copy of the url it works.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://id.test.com/obrareq.cgi?encquery%3DE6zb4nAIzYfopY8L5SbbJJPLfvrkN7Y1RkKgv4%2FSzBKmT1cY%2BhRn0A3AhCDxGFIB10DLwLMp%2BcR40CHFKhdrh2aZcEck%2Bd2pzikJ3WzWCAo5LiVW8O3CGPVoeFXUBY2orJxN9zSZXNXkAzg%2F%2F2twT%2FS1ZIUlox8fyQrKf6mITSrqbgKhn5dcC5CR79rJDCO75VEIU472JptWmPlBlEkyFT1XRO%2BUzXQHUwui92%2FGCh34PbbDrPajiyU71ycb03ffcCt0Sl1tKVNw2S%2BsUe81VH1jgV8yLWXslvl2SzsqpQUcZVZdi80HEM2ppQTsvECX%2BiyWnZ49nVBxp3YqU4nlhkAIaNaEbTEpPVF%2FvCJSuHo%3D%20agentid%3DWgtest%20ver%3D1%20crmethod%3D2y');
```

Any idea of what i did wrong?
        ......

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) which will do this for you?

Comment: Because followlocation is not working, the only I made it work is with manualy seeting the location: url.

Comment: If `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is not working, and manually parsing the `Location` header out and trying to fetch that is not working, have you considered that maybe the site serving the target URL is not working?

Comment: If I put out manually the location it works, see my last code

Comment: I find my solution. I have to add TRIM to remove blank space